# Prioritized Replay: How does the rank-based prioritization work out?

Tags: deep-learning, reinforcement-learning

In the paper [Prioritized Experience Replay](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1511.05952.pdf), the authors introduced a rank-based way to compute the priority of a transition. They said:

> For the rank-based variant, we can approximate the cumulative density function with a piecewise linear function with $k$ segments of equal probability. The segment boundaries can be precomputed (they change only when $N$ or $α$ change).

I don't very understand what they were trying to convey in this sentence: where does the cumulative density function come from?

I have a simple thought about the rank-based implementation based on what I can extract from the paper-- not so sure if it approaches what the authors talked about.

We set the range of a segment in inverse proportion to the priorities of transitions in it. For example, if one segment has the average priority of $p$ and another has $2p$, then the range of the first is two times more than that of the second.

There is an obvious deficiency in this method: I just assumed the priorities are uniformly distributed, things will be more tricky if they're not. For now, however, I cannot get any further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm surprised that the words "cumulative density function" made it into this paper. They [don't mean anything](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulative_density_function). I think they probably meant "[probability mass function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_mass_function)" (PMF).

In the paper, the probability of sampling transition $i$ from the replay buffer is
$$P(i) = \frac{p_i^\alpha}{\sum_k p_k^\alpha}$$
where $p_i$ is the priority of transition $i$. With rank-based prioritization, $p_i = 1/\text{rank}(i)$, where $\text{rank}(i)$ is the rank of transition $i$ when the replay buffer is sorted by its TD-error $|\delta_i|$.

This is actually the [zipf distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zipf's_law). Be careful not to confuse this with the [zeta distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeta_distribution). The distinction is actually very important. We have a finite number of samples in the replay buffer, so the restricted support of $i=1,\dots,N$ is appropriate. Also, $\alpha$ is not restricted to values less than 1.

It looks something like this.
[image]

In order to sample from (approximately) this distribution, the authors suggested finding ranges of $i$ such that the sum of $P(i)$ over each of these ranges is equal. By uniformly sampling the range and then uniformly sampling $i$ from within that range, you can approximate sampling from $P(i)$.

Comment: Thank you for answering. But how do we compute $rank(i)$ in the rank-based variant?

Comment: Good question. By sorting the replay buffer by the TD error. I'll edit to add.

Comment: If we take the TD error as the rank, how can we precompute the segment boundaries as I cited in the question?

Comment: I think I answered that in my last paragraph. For more specifics, you can look at [my implementation](https://github.com/philiptkd/DQN/blob/master/zipf.py).

Comment: Hi, thanks. It seems to me that $rank(i)$ here is the index of its position in a sorted array, do I understand it right?

Comment: Yes, but it's 1-indexed, not 0-indexed. The highest priority transition has rank 1.